# Sort input text file and output file in ascending order (perl)

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I am new to programming with perl and I am having issues with how to approach this problem in my assignment. It's pretty simple-- subroutine reads in an input text file where each line contains last name, first name, and score (in that order), separated from each other by a single blank:

```
Williams John 999
Desplat Alexandre 123
Zimmer Hans 234
Newman Thomas 637
```

etc.
Output will look just like the input file, just that they are in order according to last name.

I was thinking that I should be using an associative array/hash? I can't use in perl's built in 'sort' function. If someone could explain/describe how I could implement a hash here, that would be excellent.

Comment: Why not sort function, is it a homework?

Answer (score 2):

Try this (revised version suggested by @Zaid, thank you):

```
perl -e 'print sort <>' data_file
```

If you cannot use Perl builtin `sort`, then you need to implement your own sort routine. For example:

```
sub mySort {
        return @_ if @_ <= 1;

        my $pivot = shift;

        return (mySort (grep { $_ le $pivot } @_),
                $pivot,
                mySort (grep { $_ gt $pivot } @_));
}
```

Comment: Or simply `$ perl -e 'print sort <>'`

Comment: @Zaid Oh, this one is much better. Thank you. Answer updated.

Comment: @leeduhem thank you! This was very helpful. Sorry for the nubby question, but what does the my `$pivot = shift;` do exactly?

Comment: @user3462362 `$pivot = shift;` equals `$pivot = shift @_;`, which means put the first argument of `mySort` to `$pivot`. You can find further details in `perldoc -f shift`.